# What's the generic-case complexity of the Halting Problem on LBAs?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, computability

I'm familiar with Hamkins' result that the *generic-case complexity* of the Halting Problem is polynomial in time.

What's the analogous result for the various **Linear Bounded Automata**?

**Edit:** For those unfamiliar with generic-case complexity, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic-case_complexity#Basic_definitions) is the definition from Wikipedia. The proof of the generically-polynomial complexity of the Halting Problem can be found in [this](http://jdh.hamkins.org/tag/halting-problem/) paper.

The "one sentence version" of the paper is that there exists some algorithm such that the proportion of $n$-state Turing Machines for which the Halting Problem is decidable (using that algorithm) becomes 100% as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Can this question get some links for us ignorant to these type of things? Maybe [this](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ndjfl/1168352664) is a good resource?  I am not sure. I think the expression "the Halting Problem is Polynomial in Time"  looks a little strange without more context. Isn't the halting problem the famously undecidable problem? Maybe I am just whining. But I certainly could learn more about this question if I was given a little more context.

Comment: Of course! Sorry about that @Mason!

I'm just so used to people here seeming passive-aggressive about explaining "well-known concepts" that I assumed I shouldn't say anything. I hope what I added explains any problems!

Comment: The halting problem for LBAs is already 100% decidable by Turing machine, and I don't see a way of perturbing the definition to get something interesting. What motivated this question?

Comment: I wanted to know whether it would be quicker than polynomial for LBAs.

Comment: @realdonaldtrump: I know that it's decidable but my point is that the Halting Problem is not just generically decidable, it's generically *polynomial*. I wondered if the LBA-Halting-Problem might have an even greater speedup generically.